# How can I differentiate between types in a union type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a prop in a React component that is a union type made up of two types. The prop is passed down to two different sub-components, each accepting the prop as one of the types in the union type.

However, TypeScript correctly tells me that the union type is not assignable to the prop of what gets passed to the sub-components because it could be of either type.

Here's a very simplified version:

```
type A = { name: string }
type B = { age: number }

type Prop = A | B

const propThatCouldBeOfTypeAOrB: Prop = { name: 'rob' }

console.log('prop - ', propThatCouldBeOfTypeAOrB.age) // Property 'age' does not exist on type 'A'.
```

I need the union type as the prop, could be of either type, and I can't change the type that either sub-component accepts.

Is there a correct approach that tells TypeScript what type the prop is without casting the type?

Comment: `if ("name" in aORb) { /* this is definitely A */ } else { /* this is definitely B */}` would work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: Ok thanks, that would work with the simple example above, but in reality these types are complex objects

Comment: Then read the rest of the page about how narrowing works and make your criteria accordingly. This could be a user type guard or you could decide to build a discriminated union. Or both.

Comment: A [mre] should be simple but not so simple that it fails to address use cases you really care about.  If the complex objects have keys that can distinguish them, then [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) will work.  If not, then please [edit] your code example to show a case where it doesn't work and someone can address it.

Comment: Also, right now the issue is not reproducible, even for a simple example. You have an error because the compiler knows for sure that `propThatCouldBeOfTypeAOrB` is an `A` and not a `B`, due to [narrowing on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments). If you change it to `name` instead of `age` then [the problem disappears](https://tsplay.dev/mxBpZw).  You want to write `const propThatCouldBeOfTypeAOrB = { name: 'rob' } as Prop;` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5B1w), or just make it a function parameter like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N54dBw).

Comment: Thanks all, I was able to 'solve' it by adding a narrowing check using the `in` keyword for one type, and casting the other before passing them down as props.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
interface A {
    name: string;
}
interface B {
    age: number;
}

type Prop<T = undefined | A | B> = T extends A ? A : B;

const propAValue: Prop = {name: 'rob'};
const propBValue: Prop = {age: 50};

console.log('prop - ', propAValue.name);
console.log('prop - ', propBValue.age);
```

considere use interfaces instead type to records

Comment: I don't really see how this engages with the question.  The difference between `type` and `interface` has no effect on the behavior here.  The difference between the conditional definition of `Prop` also has no effect, since the type `Prop` by itself is just `A | B` as before.  The only thing you've changed here is that you are accessing the right properties on variables the compiler has [already narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to either `A` or `B`.  Can you explain how this is meant to solve the problem?

Comment: whenthe Prop type turn to a generic type in "T = undefined..." we can auto-define type with values. Then if I pass a value with "name" prop, the typescript knows that is a A type, otherwise if I pass a value with "age" prop, it knows that is a B type.

The interfaces is just more readable

Comment: That happens regardless, via narrowing on assignment.  Look at [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m0odqN) where I replace your conditional type with just `A | B`.  Nothing has changed, because your `Prop<T>` type defaults to `Prop<undefined | A | B>` which evaluates to just `A | B`.  Throwing `undefined` in there is also [not doing anything](https://tsplay.dev/wE50yw).  I think you're probably misunderstanding how TypeScript works, unfortunately.

Comment: Since this answer doesn't really address the question properly, you should probably delete it.  Otherwise I'd expect this to start receiving downvotes, which are unpleasant (in theory we shouldn't care about downvotes, but in practice I find that they bother me very much!)